# How to click more options in Compose sections using Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium

I am practising coding on Selenium Java.

I click on compose section and entered **To,Subject and Body** and trying to click on the dotted lines to select label as Social but unable to click on the section.

Please find the below code.

```
@Test
public void testSendEmail() throws Exception {
    driver.get("https://mail.google.com/");


    WebElement userElement = driver.findElement(By.id("identifierId"));
    userElement.sendKeys(properties.getProperty("username"));

    driver.findElement(By.id("identifierNext")).click();

    Thread.sleep(1000);

    WebElement passwordElement = driver.findElement(By.name("password"));
    passwordElement.sendKeys(properties.getProperty("password"));
    driver.findElement(By.id("passwordNext")).click();

    Thread.sleep(1000);

    WebElement composeElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Compose')]"));
    composeElement.click();
    WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//textarea[@name='to']")));
    //To Field
    driver.findElement(By.name("to")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.name("to")).sendKeys(String.format("%s@gmail.com", properties.getProperty("username")));
    //Subject Field
    String emailSubject = properties.getProperty("email.subject");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='subjectbox']")).sendKeys(emailSubject);
    //Body
    String emailBody = properties.getProperty("email.body"); 
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='Ar Au']//div")).sendKeys(emailBody);

        //More options----Line where I am unable to click on the dotted lines to mark label as social.

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id=':q6']/div[2]")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        //Hover on Label
        WebElement Label=driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[contains(text(),'Label')])[1]"));
        WebElement Social=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Social')]"));
        Actions a=new Actions(driver);
        a.moveToElement(Label);
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        a.moveToElement(Social).click().build().perform();
        Thread.sleep(5000);



    //Click On Send
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@role='button' and text()='Send']")).click();
```

Comment: Rather to introduce full code, You should share your exception details if you are getting. OR you should share block of HTML on which you are stucking.

Answer (score 0):

It is very difficult to answer without seeing the html.
Instead of:

```
Actions a=new Actions(driver);
a.moveToElement(Label);
Thread.sleep(5000);
a.moveToElement(Social).click().build().perform();
```

Try this:

```
a.moveToElement(Label).build().perform();
    waitUntil(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeVisible(Social)).click();
```